# Numpy: get values from array where indices are in another array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a mx1 array, a, that contains some values. Moreover, I have a nxk array, say b, that contains indices between 0 and m.

Example:

```
a = np.array((0.1, 0.2, 0.3))
b = np.random.randint(0, 3, (4, 4))
```

For every index value in b I want to get the corresponding value from a.
I can do it with a loop:

```
c = np.zeros_like(b).astype('float')
n, k = b.shape
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(k):
        c[i, j] = a[b[i, j]]
```

Is there any built-it numpy function or trick that is more elegant? This approach looks a little dumb to me.
PS: originally, a and b are Pandas objects if that helps.

Comment: You have to set the second parameter of `randint´ to 3 in order to get values of [0, 1, 2].

Comment: Thanks, I sometimes struggle with the half-open intervals notation. Coming from Matlab/R/Gauss, every now and then I fall back :-)

Comment: It doesn't help that the standard library `random` module includes the right endpoint for `random.randint`, while NumPy excludes it for `numpy.random.randint`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> a
array([ 0.1,  0.2,  0.3])
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1]])
>>> a[b]
array([[ 0.1,  0.1,  0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.1,  0.2,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.1,  0.2,  0.1,  0.2]])
```

Tada! It's just `a[b]`. (Also, you probably wanted the upper bound on the `randint` call to be `3`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try iteration with a `numpy.flatiter` object:

```
a = np.array((0.1, 0.2, 0.3))
b = np.random.randint(0, 3, (4, 4))

c = np.array([a[i] for i in b.flat]).reshape(b.shape)
print(c)

array([[ 0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.3,  0.3,  0.2,  0.1],
       [ 0.2,  0.1,  0.3,  0.3],
       [ 0.3,  0.3,  0.3,  0.1]])
```

Comment: Works, but using a list comprehension with NumPy kind of defeats the point.